# Looping over two variables

Tags: procedural-programming

Suppose I have $t=4, 2, 5$ and $v=5, 7, 4, 8, 0, 5$ and
$equ=A v/t$.  I would like to calculate $equ$ at a single value of $t$ by using all $v$ values and then move to next value of $t$.

How can I make a loop for this?

Comment: `tab = Table[A v/t, {t, {4, 2, 5}}, {v, {5, 7, 4, 8, 0, 5}}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way using `Map`:

```
 t = {4, 2, 5}; v = {5, 7, 4, 8, 0, 5};
 equ = A (v/#) & /@ t

(*{{(5 A)/4, (7 A)/4, A, 2 A, 0, (5 A)/4}, {(5 A)/2, (7 A)/2, 
 2 A, 4 A, 0, (5 A)/2}, {A, (7 A)/5, (4 A)/5, (8 A)/5, 0, A}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
t = {4, 2, 5} ; v = {5, 7, 4, 8, 0, 5};
A Outer[#2/# &, t, v] (* or *)
A Outer[Divide, v, t] // Transpose
```

> {{(5 A)/4, (7 A)/4, A, 2 A, 0, (5 A)/4}, {(5 A)/2, (7 A)/2, 2 A, 4 A, 
>     0, (5 A)/2}, {A, (7 A)/5, (4 A)/5, (8 A)/5, 0, A}}

Comment: thank you guys i appreciate your help

Comment: @rabia, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.